# Build Failure in the First Maven Project using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

While doing maven clean there is no issues, but while using maven install the following stacktrace I am getting.

Stacktrace

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Failed to use environment variables for interpolation: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation @ 
[WARNING] 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building lsm Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ lsm ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ lsm ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ lsm ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\EclipseWorkspace\lsm\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ lsm ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ lsm ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\EclipseWorkspace\lsm\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.366s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 08 12:04:33 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project lsm: Error while executing forked tests.; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "D:\EclipseWorkspace\lsm"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.lejhro</groupId>
  <artifactId>lsm</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>lsm Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>lsm</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have set the MAVEN_HOME , M2_HOME, JAVA_HOME variables.
In the command prompt mvn -version is working properly.
I have done the Maven-> Update project also.

Comment: May be you are executing the program with less privilege. Try running it as administrator

Comment: The below error states it that you are running it as less privileged used. 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project lsm: Error while executing forked tests.; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "D:\EclipseWorkspace\lsm"): CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation -> [Help 1]

Comment: I think the error telling you that the privileges are wrong is a hint.

Comment: Ya the issue was with privileges and for that I turned of the UAC setting.. but forgot to restart the system, so after restarting its working fyn.. thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the eclipse shortcut or exe

```
Right click > Run as administrator
```